# Form: Post to multiple action or one based on input?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Just want to get some direction on how I'd accomplish this; I have a form

```
<form method="POST" action="myform.php">
<input name="selecttype" type="radio" value="send1only" checked><input name="selecttype" type="radio" value="send1and2">
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

I have to post files for example, myform.php and myform2.php. I'm trying to accomplish something where if the 'send1only' is selected, the form posts to myform.php only. And if 'send1and2' is selected, the form posts to both myform.php and myform2.php.

How would I go about this? Basically I'm building a form with paypal so giving customer the option to process payment later (send1only) or now (send1and2), one post wouldn't be a file it'll be the paypal link and other would be to get info to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post to two actions but you should be able to include the contents of myform2.php and there by perform the same processing conditionally

```
  <?php

  // contents of myform1.php
  if (isset($_POST["selecttype"]) && $_POST["selecttype"] == "send1and2"){
        // contents of myform2.php or
        include "myform2.php";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: @stevenmoseley What was the other solution?

Comment: Ended up not working... Lol thought I had it but thanks for the attempt anyways.

Comment: did you note what @stevenmoseley solution was before it was removed, perhaps you you would have better luck with that.